# Hand luggage on Lufthansa

Tags: hand-luggage, lufthansa

I dont understand the information in the lufthansa.com. Can I take a backpack and my camera bag in the cabin?[here](http://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/Carry-on-baggage) is the oficial information

Answer (score 1):

> Also allowed in the cabin:
>   another item of hand luggage (**max. 30
>   x 40 x 10 cm**, e.g. handbag, laptop bag), one baby carrier per child
>   or a child’s car seat or a foldable pushchair/buggy (may have to be
>   transported in the cargo hold) and wheelchairs/orthopaedic aids (e.g.
>   walking aids).

If the camera bag is max 30 x 40 x 10 cm you can take it in the cabin.

Comment: Even if it's larger than that, they wont care - as long as it's not too much larger.  I'm about 10 minutes off boarding a LH flight with a Nova 180 AW (plus another bag) which is outside of those sizes, but I've never had problems in the past and I don't expect any today!